# How to run a single TAGGED spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I know there are various methods for running a single spec inside a file. I.e.
This works like a charm as long as the spec is not tagged (I.e. for being very slow..)

```
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb:311
```

This runs all the specs tagged as slow...

```
rspec -t slow spec/models/event_spec.rb
```

...but it takes approximately two years to complete, 'cos they really are SLOW and there's a whole bunch of them.

All of the following attempts to restrict the slow specs to run end up running all non-tagged specs from the specified file:

```
rspec -t slow -e "A describe block tagged as slow" spec/models/event_spec.rb
rspec -e "A describe block tagged as slow" spec/models/event_spec.rb
rspec -t slow spec/models/event_spec.rb:378 #the line number of the describe block
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb:378 #the line number of the describe block
rspec -e "A single slow spec" -t slow spec/models/event_spec.rb
rspec -t slow -e "A single slow spec" -t slow spec/models/event_spec.rb
rspec -t slow spec/models/event_spec.rb:466 #a line number of a single slow spec
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb:466 #a line number of a single slow spec
#It seems the order of the file/path and the options makes no difference..
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb -t slow -e "A describe block tagged as slow"
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb -e "A describe block tagged as slow"
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb:378 -t slow #the line number of the describe block
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb -e "A single slow spec" -t slow
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb -t slow -e "A single slow spec"
rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb#466 -t slow #a line number of a single slow spec
```

Is this not possible or what am I doing wrong?

P.S. Rspec version 2.10.1

## UPDATE

I failed to mention that in spec_helper Rspec has been (obviously) configured to not run the slow tests by default and to run all tests if everything gets filtered. (TBH, I thought this to be the default behaviour and that's why I didn't originally mention about it)

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with(:rspec)
  config.expect_with(:rspec)
  config.filter_run_excluding(:slow => true)
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

And this should suffice for testing the behaviour:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Demonstrating tagging issue' do
  describe "some tests that take a very long time to run", slow: true do
    it "slow test 1" do
      puts "it should be slow"
    end
    it "shlow test 2" do
      puts "it should be slow too"
    end
  end
  it "normal test" do
    puts "it should be fast"
  end
end
```

So, it seems that if I try to specify the exact test to run by line number or example name it then ignores all of my efforts to try and force it change the configured default behvaviour of ignoring slow specs.. and thus everything gets filtered and then it runs everything.

## UPDATE 2

To further specify what I'm trying to achieve. I have a file that has multiple examples tagges as slow. I don't want to touch those tags and I would like to run a single one of those slow examples. So this is all piece of cake if comment out this setting from my spec_helper.rb

```
config.filter_run_excluding(:slow => true)
```

Then any of the methods: specifying line number, -e cmd line option, focus tag what ever you want to use will work. However, I would have expected it to be possible to achieve that without having to mangle with the configs. Now I'm becoming quite sure that this is in fact most likely not possible as of currently..

Comment: Unit tests should be testing behavior in isolation, so in theory they shouldn't really be slow. Is there something you're doing in your tests that you could be doing differently? Are you connecting to an external service? Using a slow database? Not using transactions when you should be?

Comment: Can you please show us your `_spec` file

Comment: Your first example, which runs a single spec by its line number, should work regardless of whether or not the spec is tagged.

Comment: @Berrlington Well, I suppose these particular tests ought to reside somewhere else. They are not unit tests but more like partial integration tests of certain somewhat complex parsing functionality. And the tests are not written by me.. I'm just trying to run them.

Comment: @Mailo I added a sample spec file and...

Comment: @zetetic and I added some information about the spec_helpers content which ought to explaing what is going on a bit better..

Answer (score 0):

I've did few adjustments in your example and it work as you want, i hope.

`spec/something_spec.rb:`

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Demonstrating tagging issue' do
  describe "run differently slow" do
    it "is slow", slow: true do
      true.should be_true
    end

    it "is not so fast" do
      true.should be_true
    end

    it "normal test" do
      true.should be_true
    end
  end
end
```

Terminal:

```
╭─@krasimir.local /private/tmp/rtest ‹ruby-1.9.2@test› 
╰─ rspec -f d --tag true  
Run options: include {:focus=>true, :true=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true, :true=>true}

Demonstrating tagging issue
  run differently slow
    is slow
    is not so fast
    normal test

Finished in 0.00527 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 57868

╭─@krasimir.local /private/tmp/rtest ‹ruby-1.9.2@test› 
╰─ rspec -f d --tag slow
Run options: include {:focus=>true, :slow=>true}

Demonstrating tagging issue
  run differently slow
    is slow

Finished in 0.00772 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

I used:

- Ruby: ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]
- RSpec: 2.11.1

Comment: Sry, mate this doesn't really help. Thanks for trying though. See my update 2 for further information..